# Rectangles are no longer resizing in SSRS reports on SQL Server 2014 with IE

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

We have an application that uses SSRS reports on SQL Server. The reports are in 2008 format (http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition).

We have a report where is a rectangle with a few textboxes, that are populated by the report parameters. One of the parameters can grow up to the length of 1000+ chars, so the textbox height ranges from 1 to several lines.

This was still fine, because the rectangle enveloping the textbox grew together with the textbox, but when deployed on the SQL Server 2014 RS, the preview (using the `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer`) in IE works somehow differently and the content of the textbox overlaps the rectangle.

This works fine with other browsers (opera, firefox).

Apart from

- waiting for a ssrs fix
- not using IE ;)
- changing the SQL Server version
- setting the rectangle width to some unreasonable value

is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only way is to replace the rectangle by several lines - surprisingly, those do resize and move exactly in the way to cover the content of the former rectangle. It is however hard/nearly impossible to position them perfectly.

Comment: Would using a textbox and making its borders visible work for you?

Comment: Yes, that is viable too - unless I have several various elements in the said rectangle.